# does element highlight in appium 2.0 for native app supported?

Tags: appium, appium-android

as appium 2.0 supports w3c style, so my question is, is element highlight is possible in android native app after appium 2.0 version?

As appium 2.0 version also support w3c style using javascript executor.

element highlighter should support in appium 2.0